# Algorithm required to solve this

Tags: algorithm, shell, unix

Suppose I have some branching code, as shown below.

```
if condition 1
    code_line 1
    code_line 2
    more lines...
    if condition 2
        code_line 3
        code_line 4
        if condition 7   
            code_line 13
            code_line 14
        end if
        more lines...
    end if

    if condition 5
        code_line 6
        code_line 10
        more lines...
    end if
else
    code_line 7
    more lines...
end if
```

I want a method that can read this code and tell me all of the preconditions for a given line.

Examples:

1. **code_line 4** is inside **condition 2** which is inside **condition 1**.
2. **code_line 7** is inside **condition 1**.
3. **code_line 14** is inside **condition 7** which is inside **condition 2** which is inside **condition 1**.

if-else blocks can be nested an unlimited number of times.

Comment: Have edited your question, but didn't actually become closer to understanding it. What exactly you need to do here?

Comment: Looks like the surrounding context, defined syntactically

Comment: If you search for codeline 7, shouldnt the output be 'if condition 5' nested inside 'if condition 1' ?

Comment: That was typo I have changed it now.. I hope U understand the prob now...

Comment: @raina sry abt that I was not aware of that feature now I am aware and I have increased upto 50%...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build or find a parser for your language.
Then, parse your language, creating an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). For your example, it might look like this:

[image]

Within the tree, locate the piece of code you want to investigate.
Starting from that node, walk up the tree until you reach the root node. Every time you pass an IF node, get the condition for that node and print it.

For example, the path you walk for **code_line 14** looks like this:

[image]

While walking, you encounter conditions 7, 2, and 1.

Comment: thanks Kevin.. It was great help. I don't know how other users are not even able to understand the problem statement itself...